# postgresql bigint too big?

Tags: postgresql, exponential

Running

> PostgreSQL 11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
>   compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit

I tried this statement:

```
SELECT CAST (2^63-1 as bigint);
```

but got an unexpected error message:

> bigint out of range

Oddly, if I just replace the exponent form with its integer equivalent:

```
SELECT CAST (9223372036854775807 as bigint)
```

It works as expected.  I suppose it's just me not understanding things properly.  FWIW the largest number in exponent notation I could use is this:

```
SELECT CAST (2^63-513 as bigint);
```

Anything larger errored the same way.

What am I missing about how PostgreSQL does it's exponentiation? Or, is it being converted to float and back and I'm seeing rounding/truncation errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's being converted to a double precision, so you're seeing those rounding errors:

```
select pg_typeof(2^63);
    pg_typeof
------------------
 double precision

select pg_typeof(2^63-1);
    pg_typeof
------------------
 double precision
```

It works if you start with a numeric:

```
select (2::numeric^63-1)::bigint;
        int8
---------------------
 9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 1):

[`power`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) is not an integer operation. It works with either returns a `double` or `numeric`.

```
select cast(2^63-1 as bigint);
```

Expands out as

```
select cast( (power(2, 63) - 1) as bigint );
```

`power(2, 63)` here returns a `double` which at that size has an imprecision of about 512.

If you instead start with `numeric` it will use `numeric`.

```
select (power(2::numeric, 63) - 1)::bigint;
            int8         
---------------------
 9223372036854775807
```